# serve html files with laravel

Tags: html, laravel, routes, static

I have a laravel application that is working, but I need to display HTML files and assets (css and images), the web files were exported from another application built with python, so the HTML pages are very much (in hundreds), so I cannot be able to route each and every one of the pages.
I used the code below to  route to the index page, but when I click on the link to another page, it returns 404

```
// Route::get('/index', function () {
//  return file_get_contents(public_path() . '/pages/index.html');
// });
```

Please, how can I serve the pages, the folder is in the public folder of my laravel app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by embedding it in an iframe tag in the blade file
What I did was, I hosted the web files generated from the python application on AWS S3 bucket, then I hosted the Laravel application on AWS Beanstalk, then I copy the S3 endpoint and embed it in the Laravel blade file using iframe, with this the web files are hidden under the authentication of the laravel app.