# Laravel return html page with files css, js, images

Tags: laravel

I would be very grateful to solve the following problem.

I have files located in /storage/manuals. These files contain many .html pages with CSS, js, images. How to serve these HTML pages without errors 404 for every file?

I can return only one page in the controller, for example, index.html. But I`m getting errors 404 for CSS, js, images and I can not follow the links.

The placement option in the catalog /public/manuals does not fit because I need to use authentication.

Here [serve HTML files with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068159/serve-html-files-with-laravel) I found a solution, maybe someone had experience and will be able to suggest

Comment: Why don't you just use middleware to restrict access to only logged in users?

Comment: @Aless55 You mean middleware to restrict access for /public folder? I've already tried it but haven't worked yet. If you could give an example, I would be very grateful. If You mean to use middleware to /storage folder I already use it, but the problem is different (404).

Comment: you can use them like your normal resources and make a controller for them, afterwards restrict the controllers use.

Comment: How to understand this? Laravel does not process the folder /public. Is it possible to register access to controller for public url in routes?